# Android drawing a line to follow your finger

Tags: java, android

based on the answer of this question:[Android drawing a line to follow your finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300399/android-drawing-a-line-to-follow-your-finger)

I tried my solution (see the code), but i get a shape like spaghetti.. How to get rid of the previous lines? I want to draw a straight line like in Microsoft Paint.

here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {



    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

          downx = event.getX();
          downy = event.getY();
        invalidate();

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        upx = event.getX();
        upy = event.getY();
        mCanvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, mPaint);

        invalidate();

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();                 
         mCanvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, mPaint);
        invalidate();

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you all!

PS: It's not duplicated question,i explained above!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't draw in `onTouchEvent`, don't store a reference to `canvas`, move `drawLine` to

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { ... }
```

`invalidate()` will call `draw()` for you which in turn calls `onDraw()`.

In general: use UI events like `onTouchEvent` and `onClick` to modify the state of the view, then call `invalidate()` from those events and implement `onDraw` so it always renders the state of the object.

#### FingerLine.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.*;

public class FingerLine extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;

    public FingerLine(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FingerLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                // Set the end to prevent initial jump (like on the demo recording)
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<net.twisterrob.android.view.FingerLine
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: example]

**Note**: I'm using `<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`, but I don't think that could make a difference.

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: Thank you! but i'm still having the spaghetti, how i can solve that?

Comment: I didn't try my code before, but now I tried, and it does exactly: "*I want to draw a straight line like in Microsoft Paint.*" Updated my code to include all important pieces except package-related stuff.

Comment: but the line disappears after you touch the screen again.. I'm going to give you credit for this answer, because it's helped me to find the solution.. check my answer.Thank you!

Comment: You were also asking for "How to get rid of the previous lines?"... If you want to keep them: in touch UP store the coordinates of the just created line in a list and draw multiple lines from the list in `onDraw`. The "state" of your custom view is the drawn lines.

Comment: invalidate() can also be called outside switch statement

Comment: @XarEAhmer Yes, it can, but from teaching and maintenance perspective it's a better not to. For one it clearly shows which events will invalidate, and on the other hand if you handle more events (e.g. multitouch) you may not want to invalidate. Or in the future there may be different conditions (`if`) in each `case` and having clear intention in code helps to understand the existing code better. Remember that this is just an minimal impl, it needs more work to get it done.

Comment: great answered.

Comment: @TWiStErRob, your solution works good for me. But unfortunately now the lines are invisible until I touch up.
Added this before invalidate() in ACTION_UP:
  linesCoords.add(lineStartX);
  linesCoords.add(lineStartY);
  linesCoords.add(lineEndX);
  linesCoords.add(lineEndY);

and in my onDraw I call this:
canvas.drawLines(linesCoords.toFloatArray(),paint);

How can I make the lines visibly follow my finger and that the canvas will keep previous added lines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the background color of the View, in the onDraw() function before your line drawing code call `Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)`, replacing WHITE with whatever your background color is.  Or you can just call the `super.onDraw(canvas)` function in onDraw() before any of the other code.

Sorry for the lack of examples, I'm writing this from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution that make the line follows the finger. (and doesn't disappear after)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.*;

public class FingerLine extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;
    public Canvas mCanvas;

    public FingerLine(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                         }else {
                             mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, height,     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                         
                         }
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    public FingerLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                mcanvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, man. You lost part of code. As I understand there is a condition in first FingerLine constructor. But what is the condition? You lost part of code. What I need to write there?

Comment: Also, where do you define width and height for the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the kotlin version of the answer..

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View

class FingerLineView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
    private var mPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private var startX = 0f
    private var startY = 0f
    private var endX = 0f
    private var endY = 0f

    init {
        mPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mPaint.color = Color.RED
        mPaint.strokeWidth = 4f
        mPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event!!.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                startX = event.x
                startY = event.y
                // Set the end to prevent initial jump (like on the demo recording)
                endX = event.x
                endY = event.y
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                endX = event.x
                endY = event.y
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                endX = event.x
                endY = event.y
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
How can I create multiple lines to follow my finger without having the previous line being disappeared after ACTION_UP?

Comment: If you mean multiple fingers, then you can use pointers and pointer index to keep track of pressed fingers.

Comment: Thanks, actually I was looking for drawing lines (and not a single line), each line being drawn while following the finger. I managed to solve it eventually.